# How to open redo panel when calling an operator directly through code?

Tags: python

I have a question about activating the redo panel when calling an operator through code as opposed to using the Operator Search menu.

In the following example I call `bpy.ops.view3d.test_redo_panel()` but it only runs the execute method once without opening the redo panel. If I instead run the operator via the F3 operator search menu then the redo panel will show up.

Does anyone know how to get the redo panel to activate when calling an operator directly through code? Thanks for any help.

```
import bpy


class VIEW3D_OT_redo_panel_test(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'view3d.test_redo_panel'
    bl_label = 'Test Redo Panel'
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    test_int: bpy.props.IntProperty(name='Test Int', default=1)

    def execute(self, context):
        print(self.test_int)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_OT_redo_panel_test)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_OT_redo_panel_test)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()    
    bpy.ops.view3d.test_redo_panel()
```

Comment: IIRC it's a feature.  The Last Operator Adjust Panel is a UX thing, so it is only available when operators are called interactively, which can be either through the operator search if they're registered, or through being invoked from a panel layout.  There might be a context override to support it but I can't find one.

Comment: @MartyFouts Maybe by overriding with a 3D viewport area / region ?

Comment: @Gorgious I tried that before I posted but it didn't work.  I tried several other ideas but there doesn't seem to be an override that fools Blender into thinking its interactive.  I searched the usual places and couldn't find any references to such a technique in chat or devtalk either.

Comment: I'm aso interested on this. If I'm not wrong, in theory using `'INVOKE_DEFAULT'` will simulate that the OT is called "like an human" (from the search bar or from clicking a button). So, again, in theory calling  `bpy.ops.view3d.test_redo_panel('INVOKE_DEFAULT')` should work.

But it doesn't ._.